# I want validate three field dob, allow user to register only if user cross 18 years old

Tags: angularjs

I want allow user only if he crosses 18 years.  Here is my controller and html code.

Controller :

```
$scope.days = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'];
$scope.months = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];
$scope.months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
        $scope.years = [];
        for (var i = 1960; i < 2005; i++) {

            $scope.years.push(i);
        }
```

index.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="selectDOB">DATE OF BIRTH*</label>

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5 col-md-5 date-day dateDay">
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="dobDate" id="selectDOB" name="dobDate" ng-options="selectedday for selectedday in days" ng-change="validDate()" required>
                        <option value="">DD</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-7 col-md-7 date-month">
                    <select class="form-control" name="dobMonth" ng-model="dobMonth" ng-change="validDate()" required month-options>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5 col-md-5 date-year dateYear">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="dobYear" name="dobYear" ng-options="selectedyear for selectedyear in years | orderBy: orderBy:'value.selectedyear' " ng-change="validDate()" required>
                <option value="">YYYY</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". In other words, please show us how you've tried to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the current year and selected year. then check the difference is greater than or equal to 18

```
$scope.validDate() {

    var date = new Date();
    var cYear = date.getYear()

    var diff = cYear - parseInt($scope.dobYear);
    if (diff < 18) {
        console.log("error")
    }
}
```